# $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ dense in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to prove that $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, where $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$. I have tried proving that trig. polynomials are dense in $H^2(\mathbb{T})$, because i belive that i could use something similar to Rellich theorem. I'm starting to believe that $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ is not dense in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since the space is compact, $C^\infty(\mathbb T)$ is contained in $H^2(\mathbb T)$ and $C^\infty(\mathbb T)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb T)$ (convolve an $L^2$ function with a suitable approximation to the identity).

Comment: Could u please give me a bit more insight on how to convolve an $L^2$ function to the identity.?

Comment: Theorem 22.4 in this document contains a proof. http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/240A-C-03-04/Lecture_Notes/Older-Versions/chap22.pdf

Comment: $C(T)$ is dense in $L^2$ and trig. polys are dense in $C(T)$ by Stone-Weierstrass

Comment: Is $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ a complete space under the $L^2$ norm?